# Juju on Maas, Lxc container not deploying

Tags: juju, maas, lxc

I have the latest juju deployed on maas.

I also deployed the gui with: juju deploy juju-gui --to 0

This seem to work fine.

But when I deploy an lxc container on that machine the conatiner stays in pending mode for ever...

```
  0/lxc/4:
    agent-state: pending
    instance-id: pending
    series: trusty
```

When I log into the maas machine where Juju agent was installed. I'm capable of running lxc commands no problem.

Also when I look into /var/log/juju...

I can see the unit-juju-gui.log. It's deployed and all the UI works no problem. But I do not see machine-0-lxc-4.log file

Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok either it took for ever or who knows what. I waited 2 hours easy. But  machine-0-lxc-4.log it finally appeared.

Comment: Funny enough it allocated an I.P that I could not ssh to. But I can attach to it from within the physical host. It gave an I.P of xxx.xxx.1.xxx Now I created a second containers takes not even seconds. It assigned a xxx.xxx.2.xxx I.P and I can ssh to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time a container is created, per environment, a somewhat large image download happens (a few hundred megabytes). Depending on your connection, it can take a while.

After that, if new containers of the same ubuntu series are created in that environment, a cloning process is used and that's much faster than downloading an image. That's why it was fast.

If you destroy that juju environment, then again, the first time a container is used, that image will be downloaded.

This is not cached in MAAS's proxy server, because it's a https (SSL) download.

Comment: I figured! What sucks about it, is that its silent as hell and you have no clue why stuff is working or failing lol.